# Should we destroy the [websites]?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, meta, burninate-request

The [websites](/questions/tagged/websites) tag has 27 questions, no excerpt or wiki (if it did, it might turn out to be "for questions about... well, websites").  At least 5 of those questions are "where should I ask" posts; the [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) tag is fine by itself for those.  For questions about the websites across SE, the [stack-exchange](/questions/tagged/stack-exchange), [mobile-web](/questions/tagged/mobile-web), or individual-site tags such as [stack-overflow](/questions/tagged/stack-overflow) and [superuser](/questions/tagged/superuser), should be suitable.

[websites](/questions/tagged/websites) seems too ambiguous to be a suitable tag for MSE.  What do y'all think: should we condemn the tag to the burnination flames?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[websites](/questions/tagged/websites) is (are?) no more. Thanks to Luuklag, Spevacus, and those who helped to destroy this tag in true [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request) fashion and to keep MSE's tags page a fairly clean place:

[image: too much coffee]

Answer (score 7):

Yeah, let's burn it. With dragonfire.

This tag doesn't add anything meaningful to the site. The tag is only barely related to the [oldest question tagged with it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/26680/622284) (which is itself probably a duplicate of [this FAQ question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/622284)), and it certainly doesn't describe what all of the other questions are about. It's highly ambiguous, it's not helpful, and I find it hard to believe it could be made to be useful in the future.

Let's be sure to do our due diligence and clean up along the way, closing and deleting as needed.

---

#### Post-burnination breakdown

I've managed to keep up with this burnination request to the point where I can break down how much additional moderation work the community's done as a result of bringing old questions up to the community's attention.

During the burnination of [websites](/questions/tagged/websites), previously used on 27 total questions, the following moderation actions occurred:

**Closure:**

- 2 questions were closed.

  - 1 was [asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/366734/622284) and closed as off-topic.
  - 1 was [closed as a duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/26680/622284) (now deleted).

**Deletion:**

- 4 questions were deleted ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/26680/622284), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253566/622284), [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134570/622284), [4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107735/622284))

The chance to close and delete old questions that are obsolete or no longer provide value is a nice perk of burnination requests. The modern community's eyes get the opportunity to give such content a second look and ensure that it deserves to stick around. Nice work, folks!

Comment: What else would we burn it with?  Waffles?

Comment: @Ollie Don't burn the waffles! D:

Comment: Isn't it "stroopwafels" now?  Is there enough room for both horses in the stable?

Comment: @Ollie this town ain’t big enough for the two of us