# The [expiration] date of this tag is near

Tags: feature-request, tags, meta, burninate-request

The [expiration](/questions/tagged/expiration) tag has 23 questions, no tag wiki or excerpt.  It seems primarily to be used for asking questions about aged-away close/reopen votes, but is also on other questions covering topics such as flags, deleted questions, a request for an expiration date for suggested edits, etc.  For the flags, we have [aged-away](/questions/tagged/aged-away); for the close votes, the [relevant](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136989/how-do-close-votes-age-away) [posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/age-close-votes-after-14-days-regardless-of-views-allowing-recasting) (one by Shog) are tagged only with  [vote-to-close](/questions/tagged/vote-to-close), so perhaps that tag is OK alone.  Same goes for VTR.

Overall it seems too ambiguous.  Suggestions?  Should we burn it?

Comment: We also have [[tag:expired-bounty]], specifically for the bounty case.

Comment: I think [[tag:expiration]] is ambiguous and un-useful enough to be burned. I think it's on-topic in the way that it's used, but I don't feel that it's really a useful category for finding questions either.

Comment: @zcoop98 isn't that part of the bounty tag anyways

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The  [expiration](/questions/tagged/expiration) tag has been removed from all MSE questions and will be crispy bacon within 24 hours:

[image]

Burninators gonna burn, burn, burn, burn, burn...

---

### Post-burnination breakdown

An idea stolen from [Spevacus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/366728/798831), one I hope will become tradition with burninate-requests.  Not much was done to the questions save for removing the tag because they were mostly good quality, but here are the moderation actions (AFAIK) taken by either trusted users and/or diamond moderators:

#### Deleted questions

- Two questions were deleted: [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135884/) and [2.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112517/)

#### Closed questions

- [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65223/is-there-any-point-in-marking-questions-older-than-24-hours-for-closure) question was closed.

Comment: If y'all see any mistakes or items I may have missed, please feel free to edit it into the answer.